# Set or Add in Firebase which I need to use for creating a new Database entry?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I want to save User's name in a Database of Firebase called `profiles`

[image]

While I am using the below code it is **not creating any entry in my database:**

```
register() {
   fb.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
      .then((user)=>{
        db.collection('profiles').doc(user.user.uid).set({
           name: this.profile.name
        })
}
```

I have a `profile` object. So, it is not a problem.

If I use `add` like the below, it is creating entry.

```
db.collection('profiles').add({
   name: this.profile.name
})
```

But Problem is while I am trying to retrieve it's **ID**, it is not giving me the correct result.

```
db.collection("profiles").doc(user.uid).update({
   name: this.profile.name,
   mobile: this.profile.mobile,
   postcode: this.profile.postcode
});
```

uid is not matching.

ERROR:

[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Function DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field name)"

Comment: `profile` is undefined, and the full code before the `update`

Comment: When you call [add()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#add) it assigns an id automatically, it doesn't use anything in particular (specifically, it certainly won't use the user id).  This is likely why you can't retrieve it later ([update()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update) requires the document to exist).

Comment: If you want to use `user.uid` as document id then you should specify document id and call `set()` not `add()`. ex.  `db.collection('profiles').doc(user.uid).set({name: this.profile.name})`

Comment: Are you handling the promise after the ```set``` method is called?

Comment: @zkohi, I am doing what you have mentioned. But not working!! I gave that code also in my question.

Comment: @Joshi, How to handle promise, I don't know that.

Comment: @robsiemb, You are right. But what is the right approach to do it??

Comment: @Peter, full code before the update means?  Then why set is not working. It is not creating any entry!

Comment: @aspile as methoned above, if you need to ensure that the key is a particular value, you have to use `set()`.

Comment: I have created a collection and set uid is random. While I will register then I will save the user name in that collection. Eg. Profiles.

Comment: Could you debug like `console.log(this.profile)` before `update()`?